# Laravel посчитать количество отношений

Tags: php, laravel

Задача следующая - я делаю выборку из модели

```
$items = \App\Item::whereIn('id',[1,2,3,4]);
```

у каждого `item` есть отношение

```
public function relations() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Model\Relation::class);
}
```

и

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

Так вот, в мне нужно в любом виде (коллекция, массив и т.д.) получить количесво существующий отношений `relations` для каждого `user`.

У самого пока вариантов нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тугодумы прости Господи. Пришлось воспользоваться обычным sql, а не заморачиваться с этим laravelем

```
$relations_count = \DB::table('items')
        ->leftJoin('relations', function($join)
                     {
                         $join->on('items.id', '=', 'relations.item_id');
                         $join->on('items.user_id','=','relations.user_id');
                     })
        ->select('items.id', \DB::raw('COUNT(relations.id) as relations_count'))
        ->whereIn('items.id', [1,2,3,4])
        ->groupBy('items.id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$user->relations->count();
```

Comment: Так вот, в мне нужно в любом виде (коллекция, массив и т.д.) получить количесво существующий отношений relations для каждого user.

Comment: [laravel.io](https://laravel.io/forum/05-03-2014-eloquent-get-count-relation)